# I want to invest $6500 in a account earning 3.5% simple interest. After 4 years how much total money? Round cent.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Suppose you want to invest $6500 in an account that earns 3.5% simple interest. How much money will you have total at the end of 4 years? Round to the nearest cent.

This is a question on my Algebra test that I got wrong, and I'm not sure what was incorrect about my answer.

This is what I did:

I = Prt

I = 6500 × 0.33 × 4

$46428.60

Comment: This isn't an abstract algebra question so perhaps you should change the tag. Also you need to specify the period. Is the interest annually?

Comment: Yes I know but it won't let me add any other tag because I don't have many reputation s

Comment: The **interest** earned is $(6500)(0.035)(4)$. Add this to your original amount to get how much money you have after $4$ years.  I do not understand your calculation, where the $0.33$ comes from, nor the $46000$ plus, which is definitely nowhere near $(6500)(0.33)(4)$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a first-order difference equation.

Let $P_n$ denote the amount in the account after $n$ years. The accumulation of interest is described by;

$P_{n+1}$ $=$ $P_n$ $+$  $(I/100)(P_0)$, where I is the interest rate - $I$% per annum.

$P_{0+1}$ $=$ $P_1$ $=$ $P_0$ $+$ $(I/100)P_0$

That implies that $P_1$ $=$ $6,720.50

$P_2$ $=$ $P_1$ $+$ $0.035(6500)$

Continue until $P_4$ which should give you $7410

Hope this helped.

Comment: The accumulation of compound interest is described by

$P_{n+1}$ $=$ $P_n$ $+$ $(I/100)P_n$

Comment: @RossMillikan, I used a simple interest calculator to confirm my answer as well and it's the same answer as I wrote above